# Why is the axis of rotation about O? (picture)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotation

[image: Problem]

[image: part b]

I'm not understanding part b. Why is the rotation about O? Shouldn't it be about C? If you do it about C you get a different answer because you'd get the same angular velocity but a different radius to find a_y. Why did they even add point c to the diagram if it's rotating about O? If I drew the diagram for the rotation about O, I'd just have the alpha about O, what are all those other vectors? On my rolling motion diagram you'd just have an a_y and an a_x. Why separate a_o from those two?

Comment: O always remains the same height above the table. O is moving horizontally along the table while the half cylinder is rotating around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the very first image, where the object is standing on end. Points G and the point marked later as the "instantaneous center" C are at height $r$ above the table. As the object rolls, they both drop down until C is on the table. So from the kinematical view, neither G nor C can be the center because they are rotating around another point, namely the center of translation O.

Of course, the kinematical approach uses a particular schema for calculating angular momentum. Note the free-body diagram in the second half of b) which calculates the rotation around G. When calculating a rotation you actually *specify* a center and calculate around it.

Comment: but why is 4r/3pi the radius of r in the freebody diagram in the second half of b for the angular acceleration?

Comment: shouldn't the radius just be zero since it's the distance from axis of rotation to the point considered?

Comment: If you take the radius as zero, then you get a calculated angular velocity of zero as well, which is true at the axis being considered but not useful for the solution to b). The OG distance is given as 4r/3π in the problem statement, and O is the 'centri-' to the centripetal force holding the object together (the upward arrow from G at the second free-body diagram) so the OG distance is used rather than GC distance.